# Generate google map on the fly

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, settimeout

**EDITED**

**Long press the orange button at the bottom of the page to activate what i'm talking about, then press the the circle again, and say "hello when prompted", say yes to all that comes up there after.**

```
<html>

<head>

<title> Home </title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">

@font-face {
    font-family: "Roboto";
    src: url(System Fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf) format("truetype");
}

@font-face
{
font-family: "Roboto";
src: url('System Fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf'),
font-weight:bold;
}

body {"Roboto", Arial, Sans-Serif;}

#perdify {
         position:fixed;
         bottom:0px;
         left:0px;
         background: #EFEFEF;
         width:100%;
         height:1.3cm;
}

#magic{   
  background-color: #dd4b39;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  height:1.2cm; 
  width:1.2cm;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -0.6cm;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0.05cm;

}


#main { 
                background:#ffffff; 
                width:100%;  
                display:none; 
                position:fixed;
                top:0.4cm;
                left:0px;
                bottom:1.3cm;
                overflow:auto;  
                z-index:2;  
}

.welcome { padding:10px; background-color: #EFEFEF; margin-top: 10px; margin-left:5px;  margin-right:5px; font-family: "Roboto", Arial, Sans-Serif;}

#statusbar {
         position:fixed;
         top:0px;
         left:0px;
         background: #EFEFEF;
         width:100%;
         height:0.4cm;
}

#voiceSearchGo::-webkit-input-speech-button {
  -webkit-appearance:none; 
  width:100%; 
  height:100%; 
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px; 
}

#voiceSearchGo:focus { outline: none; }

#voiceSearchGo {
  height:100%; 
  width:100%;
  color:transparent;
  background-color:transparent;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  border:none;  
  cursor:default;
}

#voicesearchstimulantcontainer {
  height:1.2cm;
  width:1.2cm;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0.5mm;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -0.6cm; 
  display:none;
}

#micimage {position:absolute; top:0mm; left:0mm; height:1.2cm; width:1.2cm;}

.welcome { padding:10px; background-color: #EFEFEF; margin-top: 10px; margin-left:5px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-right:5px; font-family: "Roboto", Arial, Sans-Serif;}
        .yousaid { padding:10px; background-color: #DD4B39; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left:5px;  margin-right:5px; font-family: "Roboto", Arial, Sans-Serif; color:white;}  
        .yousaid h2 {margin: 0 0 5px 0; color:#EFEFEF;}
        .Onesearchsays { padding:10px; background-color: #EFEFEF; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left:5px;  margin-right:5px; font-family: "Roboto", Arial, Sans-Serif;} 
        .Onesearchsays h2 {margin: 0 0 5px 0; color:#DD4B39;}
        .buttonyes {padding:10px; background-color: #DD4B39;  margin-left:4%;  margin-right:4%; font-family: "Roboto", Arial, Sans-Serif; color:white; border:none; width:44%; font-weight:bold;} 
        .buttonno {padding:10px; background-color: #DD4B39; font-family: "Roboto", Arial, Sans-Serif; color:white; border:none; width:44%; font-weight:bold;}

#map { height:5cm; margin-left:-10px; margin-bottom:-10px; margin-right:-10px; margin-top:10px; }

</style>

</head>
<body>

<!--Start One Talk -->

<div id="main">
<div class="welcome" style=""> <h2 id="welcomemessage" style="margin: 0 0 10px 0; color:#DD4B39;"> How can I help You? </h2> Ps. Say 'help' for a list of Commands. </div>
</div>

<!--End One Talk -->

<!--Start status bar-->

<div id="statusbar"></div>

<!--End Status Bar-->

<!--Start Magic-->

<div id="perdify">  
<div id="magic"></div>

<div id="voicesearchstimulantcontainer">
<img src="System Icons/ic_action_microphone.png" alt="Click To Speak" id="micimage"/>
<input onfocus="this.value = '';" type="text" id="voiceSearchGo" x-webkit-speech></input>
</div>
</div>

<script>

var map;
  var infowindow;

voiceSearchGo.onwebkitspeechchange = function(e) {

var n = voiceSearchGo.value ;

var divYou = document.createElement("div"); 
divYou.id = "div1"; 
divYou.className = "yousaid"; 
divYou.innerHTML = "<h2> You Said . . . </h2>" + n ;
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divYou); 

if ((n.split(" ",1)) == 'hello')
{

setTimeout(function() {

var time = new Date().getHours();

if (time == 3 )
{
var divGS = document.createElement("div"); 
divGS.id = "div1"; 
divGS.className = "Onesearchsays"; 
divGS.innerHTML = "<h2> One Search says . . . </h2>" +  "Good Morning, would You like to check the weather?" + "<BR></BR>" +  "<button type='button' class='buttonyes' onclick='morningdecisionyes()'> Yes </button>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonno' onclick='morningdecisionno()'> No </button>";
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divGS); 
}

if (time == 4 )
{
var divGS = document.createElement("div"); 
divGS.id = "div1"; 
divGS.className = "Onesearchsays"; 
divGS.innerHTML = "<h2> One Search says . . . </h2>" +  "Good Morning, would You like to check the weather?" + "<BR></BR>" +  "<button type='button' class='buttonyes' onclick='morningdecisionyes()'> Yes </button>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonno' onclick='morningdecisionno()'> No </button>";
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divGS); 
}

if (time == 5 )
{
var divGS = document.createElement("div"); 
divGS.id = "div1"; 
divGS.className = "Onesearchsays"; 
divGS.innerHTML = "<h2> One Search says . . . </h2>" +  "Good Morning, would You like to check the weather?" + "<BR></BR>" +  "<button type='button' class='buttonyes' onclick='morningdecisionyes()'> Yes </button>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonno' onclick='morningdecisionno()'> No </button>";
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divGS); 
}

if (time == 6 )
{
var divGS = document.createElement("div"); 
divGS.id = "div1"; 
divGS.className = "Onesearchsays"; 
divGS.innerHTML = "<h2> One Search says . . . </h2>" +  "Good Morning, would You like to check the weather?" + "<BR></BR>" +  "<button type='button' class='buttonyes' onclick='morningdecisionyes()'> Yes </button>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonno' onclick='morningdecisionno()'> No </button>";
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divGS); 
}

if (time == 7 )
{
var divGS = document.createElement("div"); 
divGS.id = "div1"; 
divGS.className = "Onesearchsays";  
divGS.innerHTML = "<h2> One Search says . . . </h2>" +  "Good Morning, would You like to check the weather?" + "<BR></BR>" +  "<button type='button' class='buttonyes' onclick='morningdecisionyes()'> Yes </button>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonno' onclick='morningdecisionno()'> No </button>";
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divGS); 
}

if (time == 8 )
{
var divGS = document.createElement("div"); 
divGS.id = "div1"; 
divGS.className = "Onesearchsays"; 
divGS.innerHTML = "<h2> One Search says . . . </h2>" +  "Good Morning, would You like to check the weather?" + "<BR></BR>" +  "<button type='button' class='buttonyes' onclick='morningdecisionyes()'> Yes </button>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonno' onclick='morningdecisionno()'> No </button>";
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divGS); 
}

if (time == 9 )
{
var divGS = document.createElement("div"); 
divGS.id = "div1"; 
divGS.className = "Onesearchsays"; 
divGS.innerHTML = "<h2> One Search says . . . </h2>" +  "Good Morning, would You like to check the weather?" + "<BR></BR>" +  "<button type='button' class='buttonyes' onclick='morningdecisionyes()'> Yes </button>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonno' onclick='morningdecisionno()'> No </button>";
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divGS); 
}

if (time == 10 )
{
var divGS = document.createElement("div"); 
divGS.id = "div1"; 
divGS.className = "Onesearchsays"; 
divGS.innerHTML = "<h2> One Search says . . . </h2>" +  "Good Morning, would You like to check the weather?" + "<BR></BR>" +  "<button type='button' class='buttonyes' onclick='morningdecisionyes()'> Yes </button>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonno' onclick='morningdecisionno()'> No </button>";
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divGS); 
}

if (time == 11 )
{
var divGS = document.createElement("div"); 
divGS.id = "div1"; 
divGS.className = "Onesearchsays"; 
divGS.innerHTML = "<h2> One Search says . . . </h2>" +  "Good Morning, would You like to check the weather?" + "<BR></BR>" +  "<button type='button' class='buttonyes' onclick='morningdecisionyes()'> Yes </button>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonno' onclick='morningdecisionno()'> No </button>";
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divGS); 
}


if (time == 12)
{
var divGS = document.createElement("div"); 
divGS.id = "div1"; 
divGS.className = "Onesearchsays"; 
divGS.innerHTML = "<h2> One Search says . . . </h2>" + " Good Afternooon, would you like me to find you a near by cafe?" + "<BR></BR>" +  "<button type='button' class='buttonyes' onclick='noondecisionyes()'> Yes </button>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonno' onclick='noondecisionno()'> No </button>";
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divGS); 
}

if (time == 13)
{
var divGS = document.createElement("div"); 
divGS.id = "div1"; 
divGS.className = "Onesearchsays"; 
divGS.innerHTML = "<h2> One Search says . . . </h2>" + " Good Afternooon, would you like me to find you a near by cafe?" + "<BR></BR>" +  "<button type='button' class='buttonyes' onclick='noondecisionyes()'> Yes </button>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonno' onclick='noondecisionno()'> No </button>";
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divGS); 
}

if (time == 14)
{
var divGS = document.createElement("div"); 
divGS.id = "div1"; 
divGS.className = "Onesearchsays"; 
divGS.innerHTML = "<h2> One Search says . . . </h2>" + " Good Afternooon, would you like me to find you a near by cafe?" + "<BR></BR>" +  "<button type='button' class='buttonyes' onclick='noondecisionyes()'> Yes </button>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonno' onclick='noondecisionno()'> No </button>";
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divGS); 
}

if (time == 15)
{
var divGS = document.createElement("div"); 
divGS.id = "div1"; 
divGS.className = "Onesearchsays"; 
divGS.innerHTML = "<h2> One Search says . . . </h2>" + " Good Afternooon, would you like me to find you a near by cafe?" + "<BR></BR>" +  "<button type='button' class='buttonyes' onclick='noondecisionyes()'> Yes </button>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonno' onclick='noondecisionno()'> No </button>";
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divGS); 
}

if (time == 16)
{
var divGS = document.createElement("div"); 
divGS.id = "div1"; 
divGS.className = "Onesearchsays"; 
divGS.innerHTML = "<h2 id='evening'> One Search says . . .</h2>" + "Good Evening, would you like me to find you near by Restaurants and Bars?" + "<BR></BR>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonyes' onclick='Eveningdecisionyes()'> Yes </button>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonno' onclick='Eveningdecisionno()'> No </button>";
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divGS); 
}

if (time == 17)
{
var divGS = document.createElement("div"); 
divGS.id = "div1"; 
divGS.className = "Onesearchsays"; 
divGS.innerHTML = "<h2 id='evening'> One Search says . . .</h2>" + "Good Evening, would you like me to find you near by Restaurants and Bars?" + "<BR></BR>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonyes' onclick='Eveningdecisionyes()'> Yes </button>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonno' onclick='Eveningdecisionno()'> No </button>";
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divGS); 
}

if (time == 18)
{
var divGS = document.createElement("div"); 
divGS.id = "div1"; 
divGS.className = "Onesearchsays"; 
divGS.innerHTML = "<h2 id='evening'> One Search says . . .</h2>" + "Good Evening, would you like me to find you near by Restaurants and Bars?" + "<BR></BR>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonyes' onclick='Eveningdecisionyes()'> Yes </button>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonno' onclick='Eveningdecisionno()'> No </button>";
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divGS); 
}

if (time == 19)
{
var divGS = document.createElement("div"); 
divGS.id = "div1"; 
divGS.className = "Onesearchsays"; 
divGS.innerHTML = "<h2 id='evening'> One Search says . . .</h2>" + "Good Evening, would you like me to find you near by Restaurants and Bars?" + "<BR></BR>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonyes' onclick='Eveningdecisionyes()'> Yes </button>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonno' onclick='Eveningdecisionno()'> No </button>";
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divGS); 
}

if (time == 21)
{
var divGS = document.createElement("div"); 
divGS.id = "div1"; 
divGS.className = "Onesearchsays"; 
divGS.innerHTML = "<h2 id='evening'> One Search says . . .</h2>" + "Good Evening, would you like me to find you near by Restaurants and Bars?" + "<BR></BR>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonyes' onclick='Eveningdecisionyes()'> Yes </button>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonno' onclick='Eveningdecisionno()'> No </button>";
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divGS); 
}

if (time == 22)
{
var divGS = document.createElement("div"); 
divGS.id = "div1"; 
divGS.className = "Onesearchsays"; 
divGS.innerHTML = "<h2 id='evening'> One Search says . . .</h2>" + "Good Evening, would you like me to find you near by Restaurants and Bars?" + "<BR></BR>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonyes' onclick='Eveningdecisionyes()'> Yes </button>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonno' onclick='Eveningdecisionno()'> No </button>";
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divGS); 
}

if (time == 23)
{
var divGS = document.createElement("div"); 
divGS.id = "div1"; 
divGS.className = "Onesearchsays"; 
divGS.innerHTML = "<h2 id='evening'> One Search says . . .</h2>" + "Good Evening, would you like me to find you near by Restaurants and Bars?" + "<BR></BR>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonyes' onclick='Eveningdecisionyes()'> Yes </button>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonno' onclick='Eveningdecisionno()'> No </button>";
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divGS); 
}

if (time == 24)
{
var divGS = document.createElement("div"); 
divGS.id = "div1"; 
divGS.className = "Onesearchsays"; 
divGS.innerHTML = "<h2 id='evening'> One Search says . . .</h2>" + "Good Evening, would you like me to find you near by Restaurants and Bars?" + "<BR></BR>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonyes' onclick='Eveningdecisionyes()'> Yes </button>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonno' onclick='Eveningdecisionno()'> No </button>";
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divGS); 
}

if (time == 1)
{
var divGS = document.createElement("div"); 
divGS.id = "div1"; 
divGS.className = "Onesearchsays"; 
divGS.innerHTML = "<h2 id='evening'> One Search says . . .</h2>" + "Good Evening, would you like me to find you near by Restaurants and Bars?" + "<BR></BR>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonyes' onclick='Eveningdecisionyes()'> Yes </button>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonno' onclick='Eveningdecisionno()'> No </button>";
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divGS); 
}

if (time == 2)
{
var divGS = document.createElement("div"); 
divGS.id = "div1"; 
divGS.className = "Onesearchsays"; 
divGS.innerHTML = "<h2 id='evening'> One Search says . . .</h2>" + "Good Evening, would you like me to find you close Restaurants and Bars?" + "<BR></BR>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonyes' onclick='Eveningdecisionyes()'> Yes </button>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonno' onclick='Eveningdecisionno()'> No </button>";
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divGS); 
}

},1200);
} 

if ((n.split(" ",1)) == 'help' )
{
setTimeout(function() {

var divGS = document.createElement("div"); 
divGS.id = "div1"; 
divGS.className = "Onesearchsays"; 
divGS.innerHTML = "<h2 id='evening'> One Search Says . . . </h2>" + "Here is a list of commands . . ." + "<ol> <li>Search - Find an item in Google Search, ie: Search Panda.</li> <li>Show - Find an item in Google Images, ie: Show Panda.</li> <li>Wacth - Find an item on Youtube, ie: Watch Panda.</li> <li>Website - Go to a URL, ie: Website Panda.</li> <li>Weather - Display the current Temperature for your area.</li> <li>Find - Find a place on Google  Maps, ie: Find New York City.</li> <li>Hello - Recomendations based on time of day.</li> </ol>";
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divGS);

},1200);
}


if ((n.split(" ",1)) == 'search' )
{
setTimeout(function() {

var divGS = document.createElement("div"); 
divGS.id = "div1"; 
divGS.className = "Onesearchsays"; 
divGS.innerHTML = "<h2 id='evening'> Search One for . . .</h2>" + "<i><p id='searchterm'>hello</p></i>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonyes' onclick='Eveningdecisionyes()'> Yes </button>" + "<button type='button' class='buttonno' onclick='Eveningdecisionno()'> No </button>";
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divGS); 

},1200);
}

/* End Voice Commands */

}

function Eveningdecisionyes()
{

setTimeout(function() {

var divYou = document.createElement("div"); 
divYou.id = "div1"; 
divYou.className = "yousaid"; 
divYou.innerHTML = "<h2> You Chose . . . </h2>" + "Yes" ; 
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divYou); 

},600);

setTimeout(function() {

var divGS = document.createElement("div"); 
divGS.id = "div1"; 
divGS.className = "Onesearchsays"; 
divGS.innerHTML = "<h2> One Search Says . . . </h2>" + "Here are some Restraunts and Bars within 10 kilometres of You . . ." + "<div id='map'>" + "</div>";
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divGS);

setTimeout(function() { navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition) },1);

    function showPosition(position)
    {

   var latlon = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: latlon,
      zoom: 15,
      disableDefaultUI: true
    });

    var request = {
      location: latlon,
      radius: 10000,
      types: ['bar', 'restaurant']
    };
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.search(request, callback);
  }

  function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
     }
    }
   }

  function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });
}
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      alert(place.name);
    });

},1200);

}

function Eveningdecisionno()
{

var divYou = document.createElement("div"); 
divYou.id = "div1"; 
divYou.className = "yousaid"; 
divYou.innerHTML = "<h2> You Chose . . . </h2>" + "no" ; 
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divYou); 

}

function morningdecisionyes()
{
alert("yes");
}

function morningdecisionno()
{

var divYou = document.createElement("div"); 
divYou.id = "div1"; 
divYou.className = "yousaid"; 
divYou.innerHTML = "<h2> You Chose . . . </h2>" + "no" ; 
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divYou); 

}

function noondecisionyes()
{
alert("yes");
}

function noondecisionno()
{

var divYou = document.createElement("div"); 
divYou.id = "div1"; 
divYou.className = "yousaid"; 
divYou.innerHTML = "<h2> You Chose . . . </h2>" + "no" ; 
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(divYou); 

}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function playSound(soundfile) {
 document.getElementById("sounds").innerHTML=
 "<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
 };

$(window).load(function(){
var pressTimer

$("#magic").mouseup(function(){
  clearTimeout(pressTimer);

  return false;
}).mousedown(function(){
    pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function() { 

    $("#voicesearchstimulantcontainer").fadeIn('slow');

    if ($("#main").is(":hidden")) {
    $("#main").slideDown("slow");
    } else {
    $("#main").hide();
    };

    },500);

    },500);

  return false; 
});
}); 

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide the HTML too so we can create a JsFiddle and test it ?

Comment: I'm having trouble getting it to work in Js fiddle, it doesn't want to run the code that generates a new element via js :/

Comment: Then put the HTML and the whole JS here so we can try.

Comment: will do, it only works in chrome though as it uses webkit-speech, also certain elements may not work images and such, but they are non-crucial.

Comment: Going to edit it again to get rid of the not necessary stuff.

Comment: don't try and run it in jsfiddle wont ever work, just download it and save it, also use a substitute image for the mic image :)

Comment: wow, I hope you plan to do some refactoring.. It smells like copy pasta :)

Comment: I dont see you importing Google maps any where, are you importing it ? It should be something like this ->   <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

Comment: JSbin with some stuff I think was not being needed for this Problem removed : http://jsbin.com/ivalil/4/edit

Comment: Sorry still doesn't work, it gets my position, but doesn't load the map :(

Comment: @TweeZz, Most is my own work and anything that isn't (very little) is at full consent of the owner, I will of course rework all scripts by a larger degree as time progresses; this is, after all a very early build.

Answer (score 1):

Try taking the `var map;` outside of the function.
The Google Maps API requires the map variable to be globally accessible.

Comment: Google Maps API does **not** require your map variable to be global; possibly your own JS code might require it to be so. For instance see their 'hello world' example here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Comment: You're right, it was a long time ago but the error back then was the map variable not having `var` in front of it, which causes Internet Explorer to fail. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem, stupid me forgot to include the maps api js library :( sorry for all the troubles.